# Lazy loading tabs material angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to add some material angular tabs in lazy loading way. But I have a question, if I set the tabs in that way (lazy loading), is it necessary to make a request to the server to get the content?

In case not, what it's the difference between load the tabs laizily or not?

I have seen that documentation

https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading

Thanks you!!

Comment: Lazy loading doesn't necessarily mean making a request to the server. It means that the data you load is only loaded after you do the specific action - in this case, opening a tab. Without lazy loading you can populate the data in all tabs at once, for example when component loads. This is not good approach if you have tons of data and user only uses one tab.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading does not automaticaly assume that you are getting data from a "server". It just means that the element will be loaded when it is necessary. This could be done for a variety of reasons with some stated in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#lazy-loading).

- (in docs) some calculation has to be done. e.g. width or height of the viewport
- Data comes from the server. But for this the component could already be rendered and check if it has data or not.
- Component contains complicated child components. This is for performance reasons so it is only loaded when absolutely necessary.

But for you question: **No**, it doesn't assume that you need to retreive data from a server.